# Book with a series of parallel Earths and a version of the main characters replaces him

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for the title of a sci-fi book I read a while ago that I simply cannot remember the name of, nor where I read it.

In it the main character lives a relatively happy life with his wife. One day he is abducted and dumped in a remote location; he eventually makes it back to his house only to find that his life doesn't exist any more (either his wife is long dead or has been with another man for years, I can't remember).

He starts investigating and it turns out that he's been taken to a parallel universe by another version of himself--who has found some technology to travel between these universes--so that this doppelganger can steal the original's version of his life and be with his wife.

The main characters eventually finds the people who have made this technology, composed of a door-like portal, and goes on a bit of a tour (I think with another woman?) and ends up in an alternate Earth that's completely frozen and the two of them almost freeze to death.

I think that's about all I can remember about the book itself...

I read it perhaps two years ago. I am pretty sure that it's quite a recent book (probably after 2010). It was in English (in the UK, if that helps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dark Matter* by Blake Crouch (2016)?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27833670-dark-matter):

> Jason Dessen is walking home through the chilly Chicago streets one night, looking forward to a quiet evening in front of the fireplace with his wife, Daniela, and their son, Charlie—when his reality shatters.
>
> 'Are you happy in your life?'
>
> **Those are the last words Jason Dessen hears before the masked abductor knocks him unconscious. [..] In this world he's woken up to, Jason's life is not the one he knows. His wife is not his wife.** His son was never born. And Jason is not an ordinary college physics professor, but a celebrated genius who has achieved something remarkable. Something impossible.
>
> Is it this world or the other that's the dream?
>
> And even if the home he remembers is real, how can Jason possibly make it back to the family he loves? [...]

Furthermore, from [this review](https://www.fictionunbound.com/blog/dark-matter-spoiler-review):

> The novel breaks out into three narrative arcs. The first is where we meet Jason, he is kidnapped by another version of himself (but he doesn’t realize this till a very frustrating amount of time later), and kicked out of his world. The famous physicist Jason, the one who built the box, has decided that he has had enough of fame and the culmination of his life’s work. He wants in on that lovely family our Jason has created, so he trades places with him. [...]
>
> Jason and Amanda, the nice lady who saved him, then go into the box and have quite the time of trying to find their way back to Jason’s world.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book kidnapped alternate self life site:goodreads.com/book`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I don't know why my Google-fu wasn't bringing this back but I just was paging through endless results of books involving parallel Earths.